# how to read the value of line on a flex loop

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe

I am a new to flex development. I am trying to accomplish it seems very basic in php where my back ground is. what i am trying to do is to get the value of a line that i am reading from a textarea. I have no problem reading the lines but I cannot get the value of it when I run my loop.The code is below. If anyone could help I would be very thankful

```
var composer:StandardFlowComposer = txtSource.textFlow.flowComposer as StandardFlowComposer;
            for each (var line:TextFlowLine in composer.lines){ 
                trace(line); 
                     }
```

Answer (score 1):

"lines" is not a property of StandardFlowComposer as far as I can tell from the docs. You'll need to use getLineAt(int) to read a line. So, something like this:

```
var composer:StandardFlowComposer = txtSource.textFlow.flowComposer as StandardFlowComposer;
for (var i:int = 0; i < composer.numLines; i++){ 
    trace(composer.getLineAt(i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var composer:StandardFlowComposer = txtSource.textFlow.flowComposer as StandardFlowComposer;



 var dlim:int=0;
for each (var line:TextFlowLine in composer.lines)
{ 
        var text:String = txtSource.text.slice(dlim,dlim+line.textLength);
        dlim=dlim+line.textLength;
        trace(text);
}
```

Comment: i was able to get this code to work. However how can i tell where the line starts and finish. I need to know this info, because based on this i will need to do a search on each line to retrieve some data using regex. i really appreciate your help and sample code. thank you Miguel.

Comment: we can get each line length from TextFlowLine. See and debug the above code.